# Why do I get a WM_CHAR message with char code 3 when I press Ctrl + C?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a simple Win32 desktop application listening the keyboard message.
When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, I got the following message sequence:

```
WM_DOWN  Ctrl
WM_DOWN  C
WM_CHAR wParam=3
WM_UP  Ctrl
WM_UP  C
```

Why do I get a WM_CHAR message whose char code is 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historical. "C" is the third letter of the alphabet. Ctrl-B is 2.

Comment: Historically, Ctrl+C is ASCII 0x03 (ETX "End of Text).